# Function get closure as input and returns a closure

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to Rust and I'm trying to wrap around a function (`encryption_oracle`) with closures.

```rust
pub type Oracle = dyn FnMut(&[u8]) -> Vec<u8>;


pub fn create_encryption_oracle() -> Box<Oracle> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let key = generate_random_bytes(block_size);
    let mut prefix = generate_random_bytes(rng.gen_range(0..33));

    let padded_encryption_oracle = move |plaintext: &[u8]| -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut input = prefix.clone();
        println!("{:?}", input);
        input.append(&mut plaintext.to_vec());
        encryption_oracle(input.as_slice(), key.as_slice())
    };

    Box::new(padded_encryption_oracle)
}

pub fn wrap_encryption_oracle(prefix_len: usize, oracle: &mut Box<Oracle>) -> Box<Oracle> {
    let pad_len = (block_size - prefix_len % block_size);
    let padding = vec![0u8; pad_len];
   
    let wrapped_encryption_oracle = move |plaintext: &[u8]| -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut input = padding.clone();
        println!("{:?}", input);
        input.append(&mut plaintext.to_vec());
        let ciphertext = oracle(input.as_slice());

        //try to strip ciphertext, to ignore padding + prefix
        return ciphertext[prefix_len + pad_len..].to_vec();
    };
    return Box::new(wrapped_encryption_oracle);
}
```

And my functions are meant to be used like this

```rust
 let mut oracle = create_encryption_oracle();
 let len = find_prefix_length(&mut oracle);
 let mut wrapped_oracle = wrap_encryption_oracle(len, &mut oracle);
```

However, I get an error about lifetimes.

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> set2/src/byte_at_a_time_ecb_harder.rs:95:12
   |
83 | pub fn wrap_encryption_oracle(prefix_len: usize, oracle: &mut Box<Oracle>) -> Box<Oracle> {
   |                                                          - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
95 |     return Box::new(wrapped_encryption_oracle);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

I get that box has a `'static` lifetime, but I'm not sure how I should proceed.

Comment: `Box` does not have a `'static` lifetime, the problem is that `dyn Trait` is secretly `dyn Trait + 'static`.

Comment: [MRE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c158f23b25bc5e6b488e164fc7444137), It also has a working example. Basically you cannot return the reference of the closure if you cannot prove that the reference owner will live for the other scopes

Comment: @cafce25 Not quite. In `&mut Box<Oracle>`, then `dyn Trait` has the lifetime of the reference, not `'static`. See [the default trait object lifetimes in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) for details.

Comment: Here is a version of @ÖmerErden's code that compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15fadba7461373af87e9818a024c06b3

Comment: Well that still means `'static` here because there are no lifetime bounds on `type Oracle` (compare with `T1` and `T2` in your linked document), though you're right I should have specified that here they are the same. It's also specifically requiring `'static` not the lifetime of the reference. @SvenMarnach